# Remove MSMQ storage limits with powershell

Tags: powershell, msmq

How do I remove storage limits (queue quota) on specific queues with powershell?

To *set* storage limits to some value with powershell, we can use the `Set-MsmqQueue` cmdlet:

```bsh
Get-MsmqQueue myQueue | Set-MsmqQueue -QueueQuota  50000
```

To *remove* the setting I have tried

```bsh
... | Set-MsmqQueue -QueueQuota $false # (does nothing)
... | Set-MsmqQueue -QueueQuota 0 # (does nothing)
... | Set-MsmqQueue -QueueQuota -1 # (fails; queue quota must be positive integer)
... | Set-MsmqQueue -QueueQuota ([System.Int32]::MaxValue) # (successfully sets quota to 2147483647)
... | Set-MsmqQueue -QueueQuota ([System.Int64]::MaxValue) # (fails; Invalid value 9223372036854775807 for property MaximumQueueSize.)
```

The [powershell documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/msmq/set-msmqqueue) does not specify how to accomplish this. Does anyone know how to do this?

Comment: The solution I ended up with: `Get-MsmqQueue myQueue | Set-MsmqQueue -QueueQuota ([convert]::ToInt64("ffffffff",16))`

Comment: I would think that setting the value to `$null` would return it to the default setting.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Basically you want to set the queue to "unlimited".

My understanding is that the maximum size is 4294967295 (4 TB). Try setting it to that.

Comment: Ah, thanks. Not exactly 4TB though, more like `[convert]::ToInt64("ffffffff",16)`

Comment: that sounds better!

Comment: The quotas are there to protect the system. They should be set to a value that is high enough for business-as-usual load and low enough to prevent messages flooding the hard drive if something goes wrong.

Comment: Sure, but that is not relevant to my question.